# Write to global variable with data selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, global-variables, increment, decrement

I want to write to the global variable using the data selector. Is that even possible?
(Please be gentle my experience is pretty shallow :)

```js
var one = 0;
var two = 0;
var three = 0;

$("a[data-typ]").click(function() {

  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {

    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).data("typ").toString--;

  } else {

    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).data("typ").toString++;

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-typ='one'>One</a>
<a data-typ='two'>Two</a>
<a data-typ='three'>Three</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean this?

```js
var one = 0;
var two = 0;
var three = 0;

$("a[data-typ]").click(function() {
  const typ = $(this).data("typ")
  if ($(this).is('.active')) {
    window[typ]--
  } else {
    window[typ]++
  }
  console.log(one,two,three)
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-typ='one'>One</a>
<a data-typ='two'>Two</a>
<a data-typ='three'>Three</a>
```

If you have more than one data-typ in one attribute you need to split:

```js
var one = 0;
var two = 0;
var three = 0;

$("a[data-typ]").click(function() {
  const types = $(this).data("typ").split(" "); // split on space.
  const active = $(this).is('.active');
  types.forEach(typ => { 
    if (active) {
      window[typ]--
    } else {
      window[typ]++
    }
  })
  console.log(one, two, three)
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-typ='one three'>One and three</a>
<a data-typ='two'>Two</a>
```

Comment: wow. thanks! Is it possible to add to two variables on one click. 
Like <a data-typ='one three'>One plus three</a>
?

Comment: In principle yes. Then you need to split the typ and loop

Comment: Ok. I only have a slight idea of what you mean (actually none > newbie ;) If it is no trouble for you would you show it?

Comment: So start by giving the use case. What is the aim of this?

Comment: I updated my answer to handle more than one typ in the attribute

Comment: Wow and thanks again. I'm trying to collect answers from a test. I will have 8 categories in the end to get points in. Sometimes they get points in more than one category in one question.  In the end I want to show the user in which category he is most talented in etc. :) Would you tackle this different?

Comment: Yes. I’d have an object and likely use more than one data attribute, but you need to ask a new question and add more html and explain more what the aim is

Comment: Ok. Good to know that this is the right track. I will update this as soon am further down the line. thanks again for the support.

Comment: Is it possible to replace the data-typ with a simple class filled with text?
Something like:

const types = $(this).find("typ").text().split(" "); // split on space.

Comment: Sure. Why don’t you try? Give some example html